# Nagios python plugin not working properly

Tags: linux, python, ubuntu-14.04, icinga

I have installed Icinga for monitoring my azure infrastructure. 
I want to monitor my DB Servers using python script which is [here](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/SQLServer/Check-MSSQL-Server-Centric-Status/details)

Now it is making connection to DB server but mode options are not working properly.

giving error which is below.

```
 ./check_mssql_server.py -H some-host -p 1433  -U some-user -P some-password --bufferhitratio -w 95: -c 90:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./check_mssql_server.py", line 469, in <module>
    main()
  File "./check_mssql_server.py", line 435, in main
    execute_query(mssql, options, host)
  File "./check_mssql_server.py", line 448, in execute_query
    mssql_query.do(mssql)
  File "./check_mssql_server.py", line 285, in do
    self.calculate_result()
  File "./check_mssql_server.py", line 294, in calculate_result
    if self.query_result[1] != 0:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the output of the connection it is making on the same command.

```
./check_mssql_server.py -H some-host -p 1433  -U some-user -P some-password
OK: Time to connect was 0.262902975082s|time=0.262902975082s;;;;
```

I am not a python expert. I would highly appreciate any suggestions here.

Comment: This is resolved. I was running the wrong version of freetds which was causing this issue. But the traceback's are not managed in the version which is present on nagios exchange. But I was able to figure it out with help of one of our python expert. Let me know if anyone need the updated version.

Comment: Would you be able to send me a copy of the changes you made? I'm using the same script and am getting the exact same errors.